# How can a DIV node been "detached" and what's the use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In this article a detached Div node is created:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1008-jQuery-empty-Kills-Event-Binding-On-Persistent-Nodes.htm

I don't understand : I thought that DOM owns every nodes. How would you attach to DOM then ?

Last but not least what would be the purpose of having detached node ?

Comment: Where exactly is the detached `<div>` node created?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure which answer you expect, so here are some thoughts:

> I thought that DOM owns every nodes.

The **document** owns every node. Each node has an [`ownerDocument` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.ownerDocument) property.

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html):

> The `Document` interface represents the entire HTML or XML document. Conceptually, it is the root of the document tree, and provides the primary access to the document's data.
>
> Since elements, text nodes, comments, processing instructions, etc. cannot exist outside the context of a `Document`, the `Document` interface also contains the factory methods needed to create these objects. The `Node` objects created have a `ownerDocument` attribute which associates them with the `Document` within whose context they were created.

---

> How would you attach to DOM then?

There are various ways to insert a new node, such as [`appendChild` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) or [`insertBefore` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

---

> Last but not least what would be the purpose of having detached node ?

One advantage is that you can build complex subtrees *offline* so that the browser does not have to recalculate the layout every time you insert a node.

Sometimes it is also useful for parsing an HTML string. By creating an empty, detached `div` and assign the HTML string to `innerHTML`, you can parse and process the HTML string easily.

The only caveat is that `document.getElementById` cannot find nodes which are not part of the tree.

---

Also interesting in this regard might be the explanation for the `Node.parentNode` property. After all, a `Node` which does not have parent is not part of the tree:

> The parent of this node. All nodes, except `Attr`, `Document`, `DocumentFragment`, `Entity`, and `Notation` may have a parent. However, if a node has just been created and not yet added to the tree, or if it has been removed from the tree, this is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for good answers to all people I can only select one though :)

Answer (score 5):

with [`document.createElement()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-2141741547), you can create an element node

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
```

At this point though, it will exist in memory but will not have been attached to the DOM.

There are numerous ways in which a node can be attached to the DOM, but probably the easiest would be using [`element.appendChild(node)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107)

```
var p = document.createElement("p");

// attach the newly created node to the document body
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

You may want to create the element first, manipulate it and then attach to the DOM so that your manipulations do not cause **[browser reflow](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)** e.g. if you're setting the background colour, border, appending child elements, etc. you want to do this in memory without each change having to be reflected as a visual change in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the DOM is expensive. You can create a detached object, set it up the way you need to (adding its attributes, [binding event handlers](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1998-Using-jQuery-To-Bind-And-Trigger-Event-Handlers-On-Detached-DOM-Nodes.htm), etc).  After its setup the way you want, *then* append it to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely create elements that are not part of the DOM.

```
var someElement = document.createElement("div");
var someOtherElement = $("<div>");
```

Performing operations on detached elements are far more efficient than performing operations on attached elements because detached elements do not have to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to uses `.empty()` which detaches elements from the DOM *and* removes all event handlers from those elements.

There is also `.detach()`, which may be what you mean. `.detach()` basically just, well, detaches the node from the DOM. It's not part of the DOM anymore; it's just hanging around in memory (as long as you keep it in a variable). This means that if you discard the variable, you've lost the detached node forever (it's not in the DOM nor in a variable).

A use case is e.g. temporarily "removing" an element from the DOM without actually dismissing it, so that you can attach it later (using `.append`/`.after`/etc).

```
var detached = $("...").detach();

// later:
$("body").append(detached);
```