# Where is a DOM element when newly created?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am wondering where DOM elements are that are newly created by:

```
el = document.createElement("li")
```

When I now do:

```
document.all
```

I see only the initial elements of the document. Where does `el` live above?

Comment: Avoid `document.all`, it's non-standard and only works in IE.

Comment: I lives purely in the memory, as a [*detached node*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8694445/1048572) - it is associated to no document

Comment: @Bergi: Unless you're using [Modernizr in IE <= 8](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/592).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you have created is stored in the `el` variable, it is not added into the actual document until you append it:

```
el = document.createElement("li")
document.getElementById('myUl').appendChild(el)
```

Here's a simple jsFiddle demonstrating this:
http://jsfiddle.net/LdGjY/