# What do you call JS-generated HTML that's not yet on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I never know how to refer to content that is generated but not yet on the DOM. What do you call that? I used to think it was called the Shadow DOM, but I realized I was wrong after reading the W3C documentation on Shadow DOMs.

Comment: I don't think there is a common name for that. I guess you could say "detached DOM element".

Comment: It's just a string at that point, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the string of HTML code, that's just a *HTML string*.

If you are referring to DOM elements that are created but not yet appended, those are called *detached nodes* (also when they have been removed from the DOM but are still referenced from elsewhere).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the `detached nodes`?  If I pick up the term I'd like to defend it -- beyond, of course, it just making sense.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: I have to admit I can't find a definition in any DOM spec or so, but it's just the standard terminology - antonym of attached, meaning "removing (the reference) without destroying". It's used in [the devtools docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks), [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8694445/1048572), [an old DOM method name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator/detach), [a jQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) and [elsewhere](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-are-detached-dom-elements).